# Reference Usercontrol in a DataTemplate from the DataTemplate's datatype class

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I have a datatemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mvvm:ComponentViewModel}">
   <v:UCComponents></v:UCComponents>
</DataTemplate>
```

UCComponent is a usercontrol with a public property called ID.  ComponentViewModel also has a property called ID.  I would like to set UCComponent ID property in the setter of the ViewModel's property.  How can I do that?

This is what I've tried:

```
private string _ID;
public string ID 
{
    set { ((UCComponents)((DataTemplate)this).LoadContent()).ID = value; } 
}
```

Error: this cannot be converted from ComponentViewModel to DataTemplate.  Any help will be appreciated.

I'm not keeping true to MVVM design pattern, which is probably the reason for my frustration, but is there a way to access the UserControl used in the template?

Amanda

---

Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work.  The getter and setter of ID is never called.  This is my code:

```
public static DependencyProperty IDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ID",     typeof(Guid), typeof(UCComponents));
public Guid ID
{
    get
    { return (Guid)GetValue(IDProperty); }
    set
    { 
        SetValue(IDProperty, value);
        LoadData();
    }
}
```

I can't make the UserControl a DependencyObject.  Is that perhaps the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a dependency property on your user control (UCComponents.xaml.cs) as follows

```
    public static DependencyProperty IDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ID",
    typeof(Object),
    typeof(BindingTestCtrl));

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(IDProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IDProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

then you can bind it using

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mvvm:ComponentViewModel}">
    <v:UCComponents ID="{Binding ID}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Another solution would be to handle the DataContextChanged event on your user control with something like

```
    private ComponentViewModel _data;

    private void UserControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _data = e.NewValue as ComponentViewModel;
        this.ID = _data.ID;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it's not working.  I posted exactly what I did, but for some reason that post(answer) was removed.  Could the moderator please indicate why my question is being removed.  I'm new to this forum and believe that I asked my question the right way and that it still pertains to the solution that I need for my original post.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but I've tried your suggestion.  I tried putting my code in a reply, which is now part of my original post.  I also figured out the I don't need to inherit from DependencyObject to make your code work, since UserControls already inherits from it.  So that isn't the problem.  I now also tried the solution suggested in the first answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/2445627/…, which is a similar idea, but that doesn't work either. I'm starting to think that it's because my usercontrol sits in a DataTemplate. Could that be it?

Comment: Im not sure what to recommend, Ive used the above code many times.  Are you sure that your datatemplate is working?  Put a text block, bind to ID and make sure it is showing up in the template.

Comment: The datatemplate is definitely working.  I have some controls on it (textbox and others) and they are showing.  I'm trying to pass the ID of a record to show.  Hardcoding the ID in the usercontrol works fine.  Thanks for the help anyhow.

Comment: Does the usercontrol require the use of the ID property in its constructor, if so it will not be accessible yet, and your sure that at no point in the program execution is the getter on the ViewModel's ID field is called?

Comment: I added another possible solution that might help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jim,
I got it to work this way:  In my UserControl:

```
    public static DependencyProperty IDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ID", typeof(Guid), typeof(UCComponents));
    public Guid ID
    {
        get
        { return (Guid)GetValue(IDProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IDProperty, value);
            LoadData();
        }
    }

    private void UserControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _data = e.NewValue as ComponentViewModel;
        this.ID = _data.ID;
    }
```

In my ViewModel (used as the template type):

```
    public ComponentViewModel(Guid id)
    {
        DisplayName = "Component";
        Glyph = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Remlife;component/Images/Toolbox/Control.png", UriKind.Relative));
        ID = id;
    }
```

And in my Resources file:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mvvm:ComponentViewModel}">
    <v:UCComponents ID="{Binding ID}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Somehow I need to still pass the ID to the ViewModel in it's constructor.  Why?  I'm not sure, but at least it works now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad it worked, if you want to close the thread you can "Accept" my answer

Comment: the reason you have to pass it in the constructor will have something to do with the timing with which you create your viewmodels but generally yes the viewmodel must know what its ID is before a binding is called on it, the binding will be called when your program is first displayed, if the viewmodel has been constructed, but its ID has not been set yet then it would pass null to the usercontrol through the dependency property

Comment: I think that is exactly what is happening.  I created the ViewModel and afterwards set the value of the ID.  Now I'm passing it as a parameter to the Constructor and it works.  Thanks